# How to download text file in readable format using Blob in javascript, unable to export in proper format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Onlick of Button am performing below operation, its downloading text file but it is downloading as object inside text file but should be in readable format
any suggestion
Below is the code snippet

```
const download = ( data) => {
    console.log('--downloadErrors-', data);
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = 'errorDetails.txt';
    element.click();
  };

const data =[{message: ["one","two","three"]}]

download( data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const download = ( data) => {
    console.log('--downloadErrors-', data);
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    // remove the square brackets around data; it's already an array
    const file = new Blob(data, { type: 'text/plain' });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = 'errorDetails.txt';
    element.click();
  };
// See mdn page for Blob constructor for valid formats
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob
const data =["one","two","three"].map(el => el + '\n')

download( data)
```

Comment: is it possible to print each message in new line instead of single line after downloading

Comment: Do you want to pretty print the JSON object? Or you just want to print the actual strings in the message array, separated by line breaks?

Comment: actual strings in the message array, separated by line breaks

Answer (score 1):

Does `JSON.stringify` solve your problem?

```js
const download = (data) => {
  console.log('--downloadErrors-', data);
  const element = document.createElement('a');
  const file = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  element.download = 'errorDetails.txt';
  element.click();
};

const data = [{
  message: ["one", "two", "three"]
}]

window.btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  download(data);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">download</button>
```

It will download text file with content:

```
[{"message":["one","two","three"]}]
```

Comment: yeah, but is it possible to print each message in new line instead of single line after downloading